Understanding the Mathematics of Copulas
I am an engineering student self-studying more topics in mathematics. For my bachelors capstone project (2 years from now), I am thinking of doing a presentation on how Copula Models (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) from probability theory can be used to model the failures of machines, especially in scenarios where failure times are correlated (e.g. in a vehicle with 4 engines, as each engine fails, the probability of the failure in the remaining engines increases as compared to before).
I spent some the last month trying to understand the mathematics of Copulas, but I sometimes get confused in the mathematical notation (and going back and forth between PDFs and CDFs). I wanted to present my notes to the Math Stackexchange Community in hopes that someone might be able to confirm if my understanding is correct.
A Copula itself is a Cumulative Probability Distribution of correlated random variables. This means that the classic Derivative-Integral relationship for PDfs and Cdfs holds true for Copulas:
$$c(u_1, u_2, ..., u_n) = \frac{\partial^n C(u_1, u_2, ..., u_n)}{\partial u_1 \partial u_2 ... \partial u_n}$$
A Copula must obey the following properties:
$$\text{Boundary Condition:} \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}, u_i \in [0, 1] : C(1, ..., 1, u_i, 1, ..., 1) = u_i$$
$$ \text{Range :} \quad \forall u_i \in [0, 1] : C(u_1, u_2, ..., u_n) \in [0, 1]$$
$$ \text{Non Decreasing :} \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}, u_i, v_i \in [0, 1] : u_i \leq v_i \Rightarrow C(u_1, u_2, ..., u_n) \leq C(u_1, ..., u_{i-1}, v_i, u_{i+1}, ..., u_n)$$
$$ \text{Increasing/ Totally Positive :} \quad \int_{[a_1, b_1] \times ... \times [a_n, b_n]} dC(u_1, ..., u_n) \geq 0$$
$$ \text{Sklar's Theorem:} \quad F(x_1, x_2, x_3) = C_{\rho}(F_{X_1}(x_1), F_{X_2}(x_2), F_{X_3}(x_3))$$
I created a simple example where we have only two exponential random variables $X_1 \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_1)$ and $X_2 \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda_2)$ with a correlation of $\rho_{12} = \rho$. Suppose my task to simulate correlated values from these distributions using a Gaussian copula (I could have picked some other copula, e.g. Clayton, Gumbel):

First, I list the PDF's and CDF's of an Exponential Distribution:

$$f_{X_i}(x) = \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i x} \quad \text{for } x \geq 0$$
$$F_{X_i}(x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda_i x} \quad \text{for } x \geq 0$$

Next, I define the Inverse CDFs (Quantile Functions). The inverse CDF of an exponential distribution is given by:

$$Q_{X_i}(u) = -\frac{1}{\lambda_i} \ln(1 - u) \quad \text{for } u \in [0, 1]$$

From here, I need to generate independent random values from the exponential distributions. I call these values: $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2i}$ for $i = 1, 2, ..., n$.

Now, I apply the CDFs to these exponential random values to transform them into uniform random variables:
$$U_{1i} = F_{X_1}(x_{1i})$$
$$U_{2i} = F_{X_2}(x_{2i})$$

At this point, I need to define the Gaussian copula with correlation $\rho$ is given by:
$$C_\rho(u_1, u_2) = \Phi_\rho(\Phi^{-1}(u_1), \Phi^{-1}(u_2))$$
where $\Phi_\rho$ is the joint CDF of a bivariate normal distribution with mean vector 0, variance 1, and correlation $\rho$, and $\Phi^{-1}$ is the quantile function of a standard normal distribution.

Now, I apply the Gaussian copula to the uniform random variables to get dependent uniform random variables:
$$V_{1i} = C_\rho(U_{1i}, U_{2i})$$
$$V_{2i} = C_\rho(U_{2i}, U_{1i})$$

Finally, I apply the inverse CDFs of the exponential distributions to these dependent uniform random variables to transform them into dependent exponential random variables:
$$Y_{1i} = Q_{X_1}(V_{1i})$$
$$Y_{2i} = Q_{X_2}(V_{2i})$$


To conclude, the resulting $Y_{1i}$ and $Y_{2i}$ are samples from a correlated exponential probability distribution function with rate parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, respectively, and with a correlation of $\rho$.
Did I do this all correctly?

The question is not completely clear to me, which is why I have divided my answer into two parts. Given the title “Understanding the Mathematics of Copulas,” I defined copula more precisely. In the second part of the answer I considered your example and showed how to calculate the copula. I hope this explanation will help you. Please feel free to make comments if the explanation does not suit you.
Now let X and Y be two random variables with the distribution functions $F_{1}(x_{1}) = P(X_{1} \leq x_{1})$ and $F_{2}(x_{2}) = P(X_{2} \leq x_{2})$ respectively. Let $W(x_{1},x_{2}) = P(X_{1} \leq x_{1},X_{2} \leq x_{2})$ be their joint distribution function. Three numbers can be assigned to each pair of real numbers $(x_{1}, x_{2}): F_{1}(x_{1})$, $F_{2}(x_{2})$, and $W(x_{1},x_{2})$. Note that all these numbers fall into the range [0,1]. This means that each pair $(x_{1},x_{2})$ is mapped into a square $[0,1] x [0,1]$. We assume that $I=[0,1]$.
Now a two dimensional copula C whose domain is $I^2$ id a function $C: I^2 \rightarrow I$ characterized by the following properties:

For $a, b \in I$ we have $C(a,0)=C(a,b)=0$ and $C(a,1)=a, C(1,b)=b$
For $a1, b1, a2,b2 \in I$ such that $a1 \leq a2$ and  $b1 \leq b2$ the following relationship holds $C(a2,b2)+C(a1,b1)-C(a1,b2)-C(a2,b1) \geq 0$

It is possible to show that $C(a,b)$ is the H-volume of $[0,a] x [0,b]$, where the H-volume is the generalized volume of an n-box in a space with some measure H contained by the rectangle $[0,a] x [0,b]$. You can have a look here H volume . The copula C can be viewed as a mapping  of a number in $I$ to a rectangle $[a1,a2] x [b1,b2]$. Then the relationship (2) tells us that this number is greater or equal to zero.
The marginal distribution functions $F_{1}(x_{1})$ and $F_{2}(x_{2})$ are obtained from the joint distribution by letting $x \to + \infty$ and $y \to + \infty$, respectively.
The Gaussian or normal copula is defined as
\begin{equation}
C(a,b,\rho)= \Phi_G \left(\Phi^{-1}(a), (\Phi^{-1}(b), \rho \right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\Phi^{-1}(a)} \int_{-\infty}^{\Phi^{-1}(b)} \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{1-\rho^{2}}} \left( \frac{-(v^2-2 \rho v z +z^2)}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right) dv, dz
\end{equation}
Where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the gaussian distribution, while $\Phi_{G}(a,b)$ is the bivariate gaussian distribution. The correlation coefficient $\rho$ is such that $|\rho| \leq 1$.
In your example the marginal are exponential distributions. By using the formula above we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{{\lambda_{1}} {\lambda_{2}} \exp \left(\frac{\left({erfc}^{-1}\left(2-2 e^{{\lambda_{2}} (-{x2})}\right)-\rho  {erfc}^{-1}\left(2-2
e^{{\lambda_{1}} (-{x1})}\right)\right)^2}{\rho^2-1}+{erfc}^{-1}\left(2-2 e^{{\lambda_{2}}(-{x2})}\right)^2-({\lambda_{1}} {x1}+{\lambda_{2}} {x2})\right)}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} & {x1}\geq 0\land {x2}\geq 0 \\
0 & {True}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $erfc$ is the complementary error function.

wow, thank you so much for your answer!

Just a question ... if you looked at the procedure I outlined on how to simulate from those two exponential distributions .... is what I did correct?

I tried to derive the likelihood function for a general copula function over here - would you say this is correct? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4913759/how-to-evaluate-a-multi-variable-derivative thank you so much!
