What can the Equation of a Probability Distribution Function tell us about its Appearance?
I am an engineering student trying to self-learn topics in Probability Theory.
Specifically, I am studying Copulas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)) for the application of modelling and simulating correlated random variables.
Below, I made a list for some of the common types of Copulas I have come across:

Gaussian Copula:
The Gaussian copula with correlation matrix $\Sigma$ is given by:

$$
C(u_1, u_2, ..., u_n; \Sigma) = \Phi_{\Sigma}(\Phi^{-1}(u_1), \Phi^{-1}(u_2), ..., \Phi^{-1}(u_n))
$$
where $\Phi_{\Sigma}$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a multivariate normal distribution with mean vector 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$, and $\Phi^{-1}$ is the quantile function (inverse CDF) of a standard normal distribution.

Clayton Copula:
The Clayton copula with parameter $\theta > 0$ is given by:

$$
C(u_1, u_2; \theta) = (u_1^{-\theta} + u_2^{-\theta} - 1)^{-1/\theta}
$$

Gumbel Copula:
The Gumbel copula with parameter $\theta \geq 1$ is given by:

$$
C(u_1, u_2; \theta) = \exp(-((-\log(u_1))^{\theta} + (-\log(u_2))^{\theta})^{1/\theta})
$$

Archimedean Copula:
The Archimedean copula with generator function $\phi$ is given by:

$$
C(u_1, u_2, ..., u_n; \phi) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(u_1) + \phi(u_2) + ... + \phi(u_n))
$$
where $\phi^{-1}$ is the inverse of the generator function $\phi$.

Frank Copula:
The Frank copula with parameter $\theta \neq 0$ is given by:

$$
C(u_1, u_2; \theta) = -\frac{1}{\theta} \log \left( 1 + \frac{(e^{-\theta u_1} - 1)(e^{-\theta u_2} - 1)}{e^{-\theta} - 1} \right)
$$

Student's t Copula:
The Student's t copula with correlation matrix $\Sigma$ and degrees of freedom $\nu$ is given by:

$$
C(u_1, u_2, ..., u_n; \Sigma, \nu) = t_{\Sigma, \nu}(t_{\nu}^{-1}(u_1), t_{\nu}^{-1}(u_2), ..., t_{\nu}^{-1}(u_n))
$$
where $t_{\Sigma, \nu}$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a multivariate Student's t distribution with mean vector 0, covariance matrix $\Sigma$, and degrees of freedom $\nu$, and $t_{\nu}^{-1}$ is the quantile function (inverse CDF) of a univariate Student's t distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom.
Based on these, I had the following question:
In the context of Copula Modelling, I have often heard terms such as "Tail Dependence" being used (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_dependence). As I understand, the term "Tail Dependence" is used to describe the ability of the Copula to model correlations in the tail regions (i.e. extremities). Apparently, some Copulas are able to do this better than others.

Thus, by only looking at the mathematical formulas for these Copulas - how are we able to determine how well the Copula is able to model tail dependence?

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

BTW if anyone is interested, here is my previous question I posted on understanding the basics of Copulas: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4912821/understanding-the-mathematics-of-copulas
